# How to send terminal commands to a raspberry pi from a c# application

Tags: c#, linux, wpf, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

My raspberry pi sits on the kids tv upstairs. i can tight vnc into it to make it play various saved videos such as "Pepper pig" or "diego" via the terminal.

I made a wpf app to show me what films and videos are on the pi. so i already have its ip ect.

my question is how do i go about sending the command from my wpf app so that i dont have to keep vncing into it and typing out long commands in the terminal.

i use oxmplayer so the terminal command looks like this:

oxmplayer \media\pi\externaldrive\kidstv\pepperpig\episode1.mp4

Comment: what did you try? how do "you" log in and do it, make the c# app do the same

Comment: so far i can not find anything about sending commands to the pis terminal. i log in via tight vnc which gives me the desktop of the pi on my windows machine. i open up terminal on the pi and manually type the command in and hit enter then the video plays on the upstairs tv.

Comment: in my wpf app i can see all the names of the files on the pi. i click one and it generates a string as follows "omxplayer \media\pi\externaldrive\kidstv\pepperpig\episode1.mp4" my question is what do i need to learn/do in c# to send this to the pis terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to your Pi via SSH. There's a good SSH library for that: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Connect to your Pi, execute the command.